# Can not increase Java heap space in MPJ Express cluster mode

Tags: java, mpi, mpj-express

I executed my program using 5 nodes, each node equipped with 6 cores processor and 8GB of RAM. I set the process = 5 so that each node will handle 1 process. In some cases which used more data, I got an error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space". I tried to increase the heap by adding "-Xmx2g", but It showed "could not reserve enough space". It does not make sense, because I have plenty RAM in each node. I only can set it to <= 1GB, but my program needs more than that. Is somebody know how to solve that problem? (Please note that in multi core mode, increasing heap space is working)
[image: can not increase heap space]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I solved the problem. The main problem was that in 2 PCs, the default java was 32 bit even it has 64 bit version. Simply, I uninstalled the 32 bit version. Then, the 64 bit version will take over automatically. After that I added _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms1g -Xmx4g in system variables. Then run command "java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep HeapSize" in cmd to ensure that the heap size is increased. Finally, my mpj program run normally.